# Firebase mobile authentication auto login problem in my android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've implemented Firebase Mobile Authentication and added auto login feature if the user hasn't logged out. But when I'm deleting and re-installing the app the app is not taking me to the login screen where i can choose to login via phone number or skip login, but it is directly taking me to Phone Number entry screen where i will enter my number and get a OTP for verification.

Here is my code:

**SplashScreen.java**

```
package com.example.androidbarberbooking;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.androidbarberbooking.Common.Common;
import com.example.androidbarberbooking.Model.UserInfoModel;
import com.example.androidbarberbooking.Utils.UserUtils;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthMethodPickerLayout;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Completable;


public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

    private final static int LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 7171;
    private List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener listener;

    FirebaseFirestore database;
    CollectionReference userInfoRef;

    @BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
    ProgressBar progress_bar;


    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        delaySplashScreen();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_splash_screen);

        init();

    }

    private void init() {

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
//        userInfoRef = database.getReference(Common.USER_INFO_REFERENCE);
        userInfoRef = database.collection("User");


        providers = Arrays.asList(
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()
//                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
                );

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        listener = myFirebaseAuth -> {
            FirebaseUser user = myFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null)
            {
                showLoginLayout();
            }
            else{
                //getting token for notification
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                                Common.updateToken(getBaseContext(),task.getResult());
                                String taskID = task.getResult();
                                Log.d(TAG, "FCM registration token: " + taskID);
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                //Update Token
                FirebaseInstallations.getInstance()
                        .getToken(true)
                        .addOnFailureListener(e-> Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(installationTokenResult -> {
                            Log.d("TOKEN", installationTokenResult.getToken());
                            UserUtils.updateToken(SplashScreen.this, installationTokenResult.getToken());
                        });

                //checkUserFromFirebase();
                DocumentReference presentUser = userInfoRef.document(user.getPhoneNumber().toString());
                presentUser.get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = task.getResult();
                                    if (!userSnapshot.exists())
                                    {
                                        showRegisterLayout(user.getPhoneNumber().toString());
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Common.currentUser = userSnapshot.toObject(UserInfoModel.class);
                                        goToHomeActivity(Common.currentUser);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        };
    }

    private void goToHomeActivity(UserInfoModel userInfoModel) {
        Common.currentUser = userInfoModel;//Init Value
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private void showRegisterLayout(String edtPnNum) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_register, null);

        TextInputEditText edtFsName = (TextInputEditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtFsName);
        TextInputEditText edtLsName = (TextInputEditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtLsName);
        TextInputEditText edtPhnNum = (TextInputEditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtPnNum);
        TextInputEditText edtmail = (TextInputEditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtmail);

        ImageView btn_continue = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        //setData
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber() != null &&
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber())) {
            edtPhnNum.setText(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber());
        }

        //setView
        builder.setView(itemView);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtFsName.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Please Enter Your First Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtLsName.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Please Enter Your Last Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPhnNum.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Please Enter Your Phone Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtmail.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Please Enter Your Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    UserInfoModel userInfoModel = new UserInfoModel();
                    userInfoModel.setFirstName(edtFsName.getText().toString());
                    userInfoModel.setLastName(edtLsName.getText().toString());
                    userInfoModel.setPhoneNumber(edtPhnNum.getText().toString());
                    userInfoModel.setEmail(edtmail.getText().toString());

                    userInfoRef.document(edtPnNum)
                            .set(userInfoModel)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Registration Successful!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    goToHomeActivity(userInfoModel);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void showLoginLayout() {
        AuthMethodPickerLayout authMethodPickerLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
                .Builder(R.layout.layout_sign_in)
                .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.phoneSignIn)
                .build();

        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(authMethodPickerLayout)
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build(), LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void delaySplashScreen() {
        progress_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Completable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(() ->
                        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "[ERROR]: " + response.getError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should go to LoginLayout where it should ask that if you wan't to login via phone or skip login.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?